# Is there any way to solve this limit evaluation question faster? Takes a lot of time in an exam.

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(2+h)-f(2+\sin h)}{(h\sin h\tan h)}
$$

Given: $f'(2)=4$

I know how to solve it, but it becomes very messy as we have to apply L' hospital rule $3$ times. It's takes so much time to solve it and it is an exam question. So if there is any short method or any tips or trick to get faster.

For eg. Can we simplify those trigonometric ratios after using $f'(2) =4$ in my solution?

[solution to the question above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2BqF.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @SaucyO'Path. The limit does exist and the answer is correct.

Comment: Do you know Taylor series ? If you do, this is a very quick way

Comment: Referring to the last expression in your pic, you could work it out like that
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal L &=& \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h-\sin h}{h \sin h \tan h} =\\
&=& \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h-\sin h}{h \sin^2 h}=\\
&=& \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{h-\sin h}{h (1+\cos h)(1-\cos h)}=\\
&=&\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h-\sin h}{h^3}
\end{eqnarray}
and de l'Hopital just once.

Comment: @dfnu. That was a pretty nice solution. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Thanks @Claude Leibovici. I don't know much about Taylor series, but I will try.